# find a substring in a string python

Tags: python, string, substring

This might be a beginner question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere

How do I search and return a substring from another string in which the charachers are in a different order ?

When I check with the code below it seems to give the right answer but I'm trying to print it rather getting True or False and also, when I submit it, it says "Incorrect. Your submission did not return the correct result for the input ('UdaciousUdacitee', 'Udacity'). Your submission passed 3 out of 4 test cases:" .... I'm confused..and I've been wrapping my brain around for 3 hours or so.

Thank you

```
Test case 1: False 
Test case 2: True 
Test case 3: True 
Test case 4: True
```

More precisely:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
  if debris.find(product):
   return product
  else:
   print("Give me something that's not useless next time.")


print "Test case 1: ", fix_machine('UdaciousUdacitee', 'Udacity') == "Give me something that's not useless next time."
print "Test case 2: ", fix_machine('buy me dat Unicorn', 'Udacity') == 'Udacity'
print "Test case 3: ", fix_machine('AEIOU and sometimes y... c', 'Udacity') == 'Udacity'
print "Test case 4: ", fix_machine('wsx0-=mttrhix', 't-shirt') == 't-shirt'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't a good place to ask other people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're `print()`ing the `else` case. I think you meant to return that string. (at least according to your assertion code)

Answer (score 0):

You used `str.find()` wrong.

```
"It determines if string str occurs in string, or in a substring of string if starting index beg and ending index end are given."
```

It will consider the order, which is not what you want. Change your `fix_machine` to:

```
def fix_machine(debris, product):
  charNumInDebris = dict()
  charNumInProduct = dict()

  for c in debris:
    if c in charNumInDebris:
      charNumInDebris[c] += 1
    else:
      charNumInDebris[c] = 1

  for c in product:
    if c in charNumInProduct:
      charNumInProduct[c] += 1
    else:
      charNumInProduct[c] = 1

  for c in charNumInProduct:
    if not (c in charNumInDebris and charNumInDebris[c] >= charNumInProduct[c]):
      return "Give me something that's not useless next time."

  return product
```